# How to add a ListView in a ListView item

Tags: android, list, listview, sublist

I have a RecyclerView that each item in it is basically a square with a header and space under it for the sub list view that i want. So each item in the main list will have a list in it with items from a xml that i made (and handle it with an custom adapter of Product Objects).
the main ListView is working but how can i configure the subList to work in the main list's item[image: Example picture].

In the example picture - items 0,1 and 2 are items of the main list and the outcome i want is like i added by paint under Item 0. By adding more rows the item 0 (the first item in the main list) will expand downwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a LinearLayout with vertical orientation and add each element to this LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(...);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

for (int i = 0; i < countOfElements; i++)
{
    View view = ...
    ...
    linearLayout.addItem(view);
}

mainList.addItem(linearLayout);
```

Do it for each element
Do not place listview into listview

Comment: thanks for your comment! i really saw that its not healthy putting a listview in a listview but how do i implement in the the recyclerview adapter of the main list and how to tell the view to be in a specific item?

Comment: Managed to do it eventually with your help but some changes - 

LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout) holder.productsLayout.findViewById(R.id.subList_products_layout);
        list.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i < productsList.size(); i++)
        {

            View line = list.inflate(context, R.layout.product_view, null);

            (.....)

            list.addView(line);

Thank you!

Comment: I did but i have less than 15 rep so it doesn't show publicly :)

Answer (score 0):

Try snapping recyclerview is like google playStore

Comment: Thanks for your answer, ill use it for other reasons but this does not help me with the list inside the list item.